# Multiple Fragmens in one Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview, fragment

I'm trying to add extra componentes to *Activity* such as *TextView* etc.
Currently my *Activity* contains *googlemap* component. Bellow map I want to add extra e.g *TextViews*.
I cant do it just by drag and drop.

Here is what I want:

[image]

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="250dp"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: I will be afk for next 2h.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XML layout file with a map and another components in it, take a look at it and see if this helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/llDetailsRowLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlTaskTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_task_checklist_blue"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/task_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_seperator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/seperator"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_seperator"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/id_string"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iTaskStatusButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@drawable/task_sort_icon_selector"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/task_sort_icon_selector" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/test6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iCalendar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@drawable/calendar_blue"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/date_string"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iClock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@drawable/clock_blue"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/time_string"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iLocation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="@drawable/pinplace_blue"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/pinplace_blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/address_string"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="onDescriptionClick"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/task_description"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/map_box" >

            <fragment
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                map:mapType="normal"
                map:uiCompass="true"
                map:uiRotateGestures="true"
                map:uiScrollGestures="true"
                map:uiTiltGestures="true"
                map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by writing the code directly in your xml file?

Comment: I tried under whole section of xml file, there's nothing i can see.

Answer (score 0):

try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frag_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```